# Creating Command Button in Outlook 2010 with VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm looking at a number of examples that create Outlook context menu buttons like this:

```
    private void Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay(Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar CommandBar, 
                                                    Selection Selection)
    {

        var button = (Office.CommandBarButton)CommandBar.Controls.
                            Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing,
                                missing, missing, missing);            
        button.accName = "SowSelectedItem";
        button.DescriptionText = "Show Selected item";
        button.Caption = button.DescriptionText;
        button.Tag = "ShowSelectedItem";
        button.Click += ContextMenuItemClicked;
    }
```

This works correct once - it creates a button on the menu just fine and it's clickable and my event handler fires on the first access.

However, the menu activation fires repeatedly and every time it runs it seems another event handler is added (but only a single button shows on the menu), so clicking the button now fires the handler multiple times - once for each access made previously - with the click handlers are accumulating (even though I'm adding a new button each time).

Ok, so I thought I can:

- Set a flag and only load the button once (doesn't show on subsequent activation)
- Cache the button and add it each time (also doesn't show on subsequent activation)
- Cache and make the button visible and enabled each time (doesn't show)

I feel like I'm missing something here. How do I hook up the button so I get the correct button activation and only a single event handler hit?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not quite sure what Outlook is doing to the button but the following code addresses the problem, by implementing both the menu activation and de-activation and removing the event handler in the deactivation.

```
public partial class ContextMenuLookupAddin
{
    Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;
    CommandBarButton contextButton = null;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
        Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay += Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay;
        Application.ContextMenuClose +=Application_ContextMenuClose;
    }

    private void Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay(Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar CommandBar, 
                                                    Selection Selection)
    {
        if (contextButton == null)
        {
            contextButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)CommandBar.Controls.
                                Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing,
                                    missing, missing, missing);

            contextButton.accName = "SowSelectedItem";
        }

        contextButton.DescriptionText = "Show Selected item";
        contextButton.Caption = contextButton.DescriptionText;
        contextButton.Tag = "ShowSelectedItem";
        contextButton.FaceId = 4000;
        contextButton.OnAction = "OutlookIntegration.ThisAddIn.ContextMenuItemClicked";
        contextButton.Click += ContextMenuItemClicked;
    }

    private void Application_ContextMenuClose(OlContextMenu ContextMenu)
    {
        contextButton.Click -= ContextMenuItemClicked;
        contextButton.Delete(missing);
        contextButton = null;
    }

    private void ContextMenuItemClicked(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        if (currentExplorer.Selection.Count > 0)
        {
            object selObject = currentExplorer.Selection[1];
            if (selObject is MailItem)
            {
                // do your stuff with the selected message here
                MailItem mail = selObject as MailItem;
                MessageBox.Show("Message Subject: " + mail.Subject);
            }
        } 
    }
 }
```